Getting actual parameter name
Can I get the same functionality with just one parameter to expectNumber?
    expectNumber(secWCanvas, Object.keys({secWCanvas}));
    function expectNumber(variable, varName) {
        if (Number.isNaN(variable)) {
            throw Error(`Expected number: ${varName}`);
        }
    }


what is the reality of secWCanvas ?

@MisterJojo Do you mean how it is declared? It is not a global variable.

Please provider a reproducible example for this.

@GSriram Just add let secWCanvas; above the code.

You want to call expectNumber(myVar) and have expectNumber retrieve the string "myVar".  It’s not possible.

TL;DR: no. Variable names aren’t data. If the name in the caller is somehow important, pass it as a string, because it’s data.

@Leo Do you mean how it is declared? It is not a global variable
You are laughing at me? I don't find it fun to play guessing games!

@MisterJojo I am not laughing. I believed you were thinking at something like window[varName].

Thanks. I realize I am already using the "insane method with the backtrace". I just hoped there would be a more easy way today.

Dear downvoters. This could easily be implemented in JavaScript itself. But it has not been implemented. (And I think I know why.)



let secWCanvas = "10";
 expectNumber(secWCanvas);
    function expectNumber(variable) {
        const varName = Object.values({ variable })[0]; 
        console.log("Number=>",varName) 
        if (Number.isNaN(variable)) {
            throw Error(`Expected number: ${varName}`);
        }
    }




Thanks, but that does not work. Please test it.

Oh, you can try it. I updated the answer and I have a request, please add a positive vote.

This is just a very convoluted way to do console.log("Number=>", variable).

@SyedBilalHaider I am sorry. This still is too far from a solution. You (still) need the backtrace. See the suggested old question. It is mentioned in a comment.
